# Swift - Alamofire "Invalid value around character 0."

Tags: swift, alamofire

I found some thread the same problem but their answers not works for me.

I have a `post` request to check user login.

> Url form :

"http://support.xxx.xx:8031/serpapi/login/checkLogin"

> Parameters :

```
["contextInfo" : 
      ["clientId": "1000000", "orgId": "1000001",
      "warehouseId": "1000002", "roleId": "0"],
      "userName": "hanoiaUser", "password": "hanoiaUser"]
```

> Request :

```
Alamofire.request(url!, method: .post, parameters: params).responseJSON { (response) in
        print(response)
    }
```

> Error response :

```
FAILURE: responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}))
```

Why am i getting this error? and how to solve it ?

Edit : i'm tried with POSTMAN and it return response :

> Content-Type : application/json
>
> Body : raw - json

```
{

    "contextInfo" : {
       "clientId":1000000,
       "orgId": 1000001,
       "warehouseId": 1000002,
       "roleId": 0
    },
   "userName": "hanoiaUser",
   "password": "hanoiaUser"
}
```

> RESPONSE :

```
 {
        "success": true,
        "data": [
            {
                "userId": 1000003,
                "userName": "hanoiaUser",
                "token": "b7e804d25065e5c3ac97d765180b7986"
            }
        ],
        "error": null
    }
```

Comment: Its a problem with your server probably

Comment: Apparently the response is not JSON Valid. Could you use `responseString` instead and show us that string?

Comment: I'm tried but its return another error : "Error 415 Unsupported Media Type"

Comment: First fix your Postman request, without a valid request no one can help you figure out what is wrong with your Swift code.

Comment: @TungVuDuc Error 415 on the other hand means that the response type is not the same as described by your `Content-Type` header. This can happen for example when you expect a JSON response and receive an XML one. If you managed to get your Postman request working, please include the Postman request in your question.

Comment: I'm edited :) thank you

Comment: Do you send `Accept: application/json` header ?

Comment: In swift code... no I don't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, finally I solved the problem

> Here's new request :

```
Alamofire.request(url!, method: .post,encoding : JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers, parameters: params).responseJSON { (response) in
    print(response)
}
```

> With Headers :

```
  let headers = [
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    ]
```

Comment: thanks, you saved my day. I know the issue is in the header, but there are any solutions about the header that I try and didn't work. add content type inside validate(), return into responseString and your solution, set header in alamofire request. it's work

Answer (score 0):

Set the request header like :

```
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = ["Content-Type":"application/json"]
```